# Running aggregate join queries on mysql from golang returns no values

Tags: mysql, go

I have the following query which returns results when run directly from mysql.

The same query returns 0 values, when run from golang program.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/rs/zerolog/log"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
)

var DB *sqlx.DB


func main() {
    DB, err := sqlx.Connect("mysql", "root:password@(localhost:3306)/jsl2")
    if err != nil {
        log.Error().Err(err)
    }

    sqlstring := `SELECT
                        salesdetails.taxper, sum(salesdetails.gvalue), 
                        sum(salesdetails.taxamt) 
                FROM salesdetails
                    Inner Join sales ON sales.saleskey = salesdetails.saleskey
                where 
                sales.bdate >= '2021-12-01' 
                and sales.bdate <= '2021-12-31' 
                and sales.achead IN (401975)
                group by salesdetails.taxper
                order by salesdetails.taxper`

    rows, err := DB.Query(sqlstring)

    for rows.Next() {
        var taxper int
        var taxableValue float64
        var taxAmount float64

        err = rows.Scan(&taxper, &taxableValue, &taxAmount)

        log.Print(taxper, taxableValue, taxAmount)

    }

    err = rows.Err()

    if err != nil {
        log.Error().Err(err)
    }

}
```

On the console, running the program returns the following values.
In SQL browser, it returns 4 rows which is correct.
The result from the sql browser for the same query is

```
0   1278.00     0.00
5   89875.65    4493.78
12  3680.00     441.60
18  94868.73    17076.37
```

But in the program also return 4 rows with 0 value.

```
{"level":"debug","time":"2022-01-13T17:07:39+05:30","message":"0 0 0"}
{"level":"debug","time":"2022-01-13T17:07:39+05:30","message":"0 0 0"}
{"level":"debug","time":"2022-01-13T17:07:39+05:30","message":"0 0 0"}
{"level":"debug","time":"2022-01-13T17:07:39+05:30","message":"0 0 0"}
```

How to set the datatype for the aggregate functions.

Comment: _Just a note_ `and sales.achead IN (401975)` would be simpler to write `and sales.achead = 401975` but I dont think that is your problem

Comment: You're not checking the `err` returned from `rows, err := DB.Query(...`. Why?

Comment: You're not checking the `err` returned from `err = rows.Scan(...`. Why?

Comment: You are also not doing `defer rows.Close()`. Check the error while doing `Scan()`. Make sure data type of variable is same as table column data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the datatype of taxper to float and it worked.
I found this after checking the err from rows.Scan( as suggested by @mkopriva